# IMMDevice::Activate return code for missing interface

Tags: c++, windows, audio, com

I'm enumerating audio endpoint devices using the Windows MMDevice API, and I want to expose the volume control for each in a GUI. After enumerating, I have a list of [`IMMDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371395(v=vs.85).aspx), whose [`Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371405(v=vs.85).aspx) function I need to call to get an [`IAudioEndpointVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892(v=vs.85).aspx).

Apparently not all audio devices implement that interface. How do I check properly if a device implements it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
// smart pointers from _com_ptr_t
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMMDevice, __uuidof(IMMDevice));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IAudioEndpointVolume, __uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume));

IAudioEndpointVolumePtr pVolume;
HRESULT hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVolume));
```

But the return codes in `hr` are a bit confusing. For most devices I get *S_OK* and `pVolume` is an `IAudioEndpointVolume`. However, for some (but not all) disabled devices it returns *E_POINTER*, which according to MSDN means:

> Parameter ppInterface is NULL.

But you can see that `ppInterface` (the last parameter of the call to `Activate`) can't be NULL.

On other devices I also get *FILE_NOT_FOUND*.

What's the correct way to check if the interface is implemented, **before** calling `Activate`? Ideally I'd like to differentiate between the interface missing and a programming or COM error that requires seperate error handling (logging, UI warning).

Comment: I don't think you can detect `IAudioEndpointVolume` availability other than trying to `Activate`. Perhaps `E_POINTER` is not descriptive but it's a fact of life that it's been returned. There might be an excusing reason for this (the error is forwarded from lower layer without good reasons to replace it with another code).

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`Activate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371405.aspx) documentation, the correct error code is:

> E_NOINTERFACE
>   The object does not support the requested interface type.

Your code is fine for requesting an `IAudioEndpointVolume` (provided `pDevice` is a valid pointer), so if `E_POINTER` is being returned then the device's implementation of `Activate()` is buggy.

Comment: Is the interface implemented by the device driver? Because in 7/9 cases of not getting `S_OK`, I get `E_POINTER`. Not once do I get `E_NOINTERFACE`. This is across different device vendors and drivers so I was thinking this is a bug in the MMDevice API.

Comment: You would have to ask Microsoft about that